# Visual Studio Code - Unused Import Warning - Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When importing the Tkinter module, VS Code gives me a 100+ warning messages about unused imports. Is there a way to turn this off? Or should I be doing something different to avoid this?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Becuase you're using `from tkinter import *` python is importing everything in the tkinter module. You then get a warning for each class in tkinter that you aren't using. You can either just import the classes you need (`from tkinter import Tk`), or turn off the warnings in visual studio settings (Tools > Options > Python).